# Which is better - Destructuring props while passing arguments or inside the function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, destructuring

I am trying to figure out which is a better practice.

```
const SomeComponent = ({ foo, bar}) => {
  ...
}

const SomeComponent = props => {
  const { foo, bar } = props;
  ...
}
```

Comment: They work the same, the first one is shorter, and arguably, more readable. You be the judge.

Comment: Ironically started having this debate lately, personally I would recommend destructing props when there are fewer variables, to destruct, but the comes a time when you will have like 10 variables to destruct and that becomes time-consuming, and being a developer that had to maintain code, of that many destructing trust it becomes annoying so if your code is going to be maintained by you then anywhere you go is cool, but if your going to share your code, maybe take the other coder into consideration when making that decision

Comment: There is no clear cut "better". It will vary mostly from person to person and a little by context. I personally slightly dislike destructuring in the parameters as I prefer to know what data I get, otherwise it's not easy to know if I just see ({name}) => {}` I've no idea if there would be another property, while `person => {let {name} = person}` it's more clear I might also have `age`. However, there are many occasions you truly don't care about other properties and you only need to extract one, so you do `({foo}) => foo`. I'm OK with those.

Comment: One benefit to spreading in while passing is that vs code will show `functionName({a,b})` in the hint instead of `functionName(props)`. When you use TypeScript then this is not a problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might depend on different things eg. on how nested the properties are and how complicated the components is. We always have to remember about the fact that our code should be easy to read. 
Maybe take a look at the below link to see different ways, pros and cons of different destructuring patterns.
https://medium.com/@crunchtech/object-destructuring-best-practice-in-javascript-9c8794699a0d